# Calling a Procedure from a different KB in GeneXus

Tags: session, procedure, genexus

I would like to know how can I call a procedure from a different KB in GeneXus. I cannot use them as Web Services, because they must be stateful in order to keep sessions.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on many different things. For example, the language you are generating, whether the two applications are on the same server, if the procedure can be called from a command line, etc.

If the procedure is Main and callable from the command line, and both applications are on the same server, the [Shell function](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?8502) may be what you are looking for. Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for not providing those informations. The KB is using a C#/SQLServer web enviroment. The Procedure is set as main program and is callable through HTTP. I'll take a more deep look about Shells, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic calls, assign the program name to a variable and call the program with that variable, for example:

&Program = 'ProgramName'

Call(&Program,parm1,parmX)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer above about the Shell Function, you could deploy your application as a jar file, for example, and call it from the other KB as an external object, accessing its methods inside the package.

Link: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32092,Application+Deployment+tool,